# Access JSTL variable define in a jsp inside AJAX call

Tags: javascript, jquery, jsp

I got a JSP file where I define JSTL variable like this (form value) :

```
<c:set var="idEtape" value="${etapeForm.etape.idEtape}" scope="page"/>
<c:set var="idContact" value="${etapeForm.etape.idContact}" scope="page"/>
<c:set var="numeroDossierFoa" value="${etapeForm.dossier.numeroDossier}" scope="page"/>
<script type="text/javascript" src=myfile.js"/>"></script>
```

In my myfile.js file, I need to use these variable but I got an error who tell me that they are undefined.

I use these variables in an ajax call like this :

```
var request = $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "/myUrl/" + numeroDossier + "/" + idContact + "/" + idEtape,
            cache: false
});
```

Where am I wrong ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

JSP variables cannot be used inside javascript file since JSP is server side and JS is client side

Try this:

```
<input id="idEtape" value="${etapeForm.etape.idEtape}" type="hidden"/>
```

In JS:

```
$("#idEtape").val();
```

Answer (score 1):

You may try using `${}` to access jstl variables. In your jsp create js variables before the file import:

**jsp**

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var numeroDossier = '${etapeForm.dossier.numeroDossier}';
    var idEtape = '${etapeForm.etape.idEtape}';
    var idContact = '${etapeForm.etape.idContact}';
</script>
<script type="text/javascript" src=myfile.js"/>"></script>
```

**js**

```
var request = $.ajax(
{
    type: "POST",
    url: "/myUrl/" + numeroDossier + "/" + idContact + "/" +idEtape,
    cache: false
});
```

Comment: This will work if its in the JSP itself and not in external js file

Comment: My js file is external so it didn't work, but nikhil answer is working

Answer (score 0):

You have to use EL expression to access this variable like below, provided that variable scope should be session :

```
<c:set var="idEtape" value="${etapeForm.etape.idEtape}" scope="session"/>
<c:set var="idContact" value="${etapeForm.etape.idContact}" scope="session"/>
<c:set var="numeroDossierFoa" value="${etapeForm.dossier.numeroDossier}" scope="session"/>

var request = $.ajax({type: "POST",
    url: "/myUrl/" + '${numeroDossier}' + "/" + '${idContact}' + "/" + '${idEtape}',
    cache: false
    });
```

Comment: This will work if its in the JSP itself and not in external js file.